# How to use $toString in $project for subdocument field on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to aggregate collection and convert `ObjectID` to String in `$project` like this:

```
'$project' => [
                'name' => 1,
                'desc' => 1,
                'price' => 1,
                'category._id' => ['$toString' => '$_id'],
                'category.name' => 1
]
```

However, by doing so, it converts the document `_id` but not the category subdocument `_id`.

Anyway to make it convert the `category` subdocument `_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$map` to iterate loop of `category` array and convert `_id` to string and return `name` and `_id`

```
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      desc: 1,
      price: 1,
      category: {
        $map: {
          input: "$category",
          in: {
            _id: { $toString: "$$this._id" },
            name: "$$this.name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```